# Pageant fails to auto-start on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, pageant

I have the following shortcut in `c:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`

```
C:\prog\PuTTY\pageant.exe c:\my\.ssh\some-key.ppk c:\my\.ssh\other-key.ppk
```

It used to start ok, but in Windows 10 it opens the folder `c:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\AutorunsDisabled\` instead (I use sysinternals autoruns to manage startups).
When I navigate to the shortcut and click on it, it starts ok.

I had "Run as Administrator" set on this shortcut. Other shortcuts that don't have this option start ok. I'll try without this option.

Comment: Does any other shortcut in `Startup` folder work? + Don't you [have `AutorunsDisabled` in the `Startup` folder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/autorunsdisabled-window-pops-up-on-system-start-up/c18792e8-29a2-4fc4-a3d0-c02a16c2af3c)?

Comment: Other shortcuts work.

Comment: AutorunsDisabled is created by "sysinternals autoruns" when you disable an autorun and is Hidden... I removed "Run as Administrator" from pageant and I think it now starts (will check on next login)

Answer (score 0):

Removing  "Run as Administrator" from the pageant shortcut fixes the problem.